# DataTrigger binding to a get-only property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, properties

Is it possible to bind a property with no setter to a `DataTrigger` in WPF? I have the following code and the property's getter is not called as expected:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Connected" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Disconnected" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

---

```
public bool IsLoggedIn
{
    get { return Connection.IsLoggedIn; }
}
```

INPC is implemented properly (though I don't think that actually matters in this situation) and properties with setters behave properly. Is it possible to bind this property to a `DataTrigger` (and have it update properly) as it stands now?

Comment: Yes , there's nothing wrong with this code , 
The only thing is you might be forgetting to Raise a PropertyChanged 
event on that property at some point , since you do not have a setter people often forget to Raise that event "By hand" when the notification is needed (like for your DataTrigger )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. Why not?

Its all fine with having just a getter on the source side of binding. Target of the binding must be a dependency property but the source can be anything.

If you wish changes to be fired properly you will have to fire PropertyChanged with property name IsLoggedIn too once Connection.IsLoggedIn gets changed.

Comment: Yup, that's all I had to do. Today is just one of those days, I guess. Thanks for the answer.